# i2c interference on coiled wire

Tags: i2c, coil, keyboard, atmega32u4

Hello good day I been trying to build split keyboard using 2 pro micro.

I'd been following let's split keyboard using qmk firmware.

And the connection diagram of the i2c is this [image]

When doing it on the breadboard everything is OK, until I finish writing the firmware and decide to test the connections. then soldered all the socket to use, when tried to use it, it didn't work now after 3 days of troubleshooting, I found that the coiled wire used in the pin 2 and 3 is the culprit.

When it is connected, it will work properly until I touch the coiled wire, I am suspecting that there is interference if I touch it, but I don't know how to prevent it, and the wire I'm using is [YAESU MH-48A6  cable cord](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/2016-Hot-Hot-New-Generic-Replacement-Mic-Cable-Cord-Wire-for-YAESU-MH-48A6J-FT-7800/32809341470.html).

But I can reproduce the issue using a single strand of UTP wire around 1 meter in length, when it is connected and running I will slow wrap my hand to the wire, then slowly tightening my fist. Then the i2c connection on the pro-micro's gone.

BTW all the testing still done in the breadboard.

I will appreciate any advice/suggestion you give. Thanks.

Comment: Have you calculated the added delay that that cable brings to the party? Have you got a data sheet for the cable and if so what characteristic impedance does it have? Are you coiling all four wires (as per seen in your diagram)?

Comment: propagation delay and characteristic impedance are not factors for I2C - it is far too slow (1us=200m). Only capacitance and cross talk are issues

Comment: @Andyaka yes I am, but on the testing I just hook-up the single wire of it, I also tried to connect all four wires and the TXLED1 of the promicro fully lt up and the connection automatically broken even without touching.

Comment: @HenryCrun yeah that is on top my head the cross talks, btw on the testing only the VCC, GND, pin 1 and 2, and the two resistor then the power source from the usb.

Answer (score 2):

With 4k7 pullups, it will not take a huge amount of bus C to slow it down. Try reducing I2C speed or increasing bus current (1k5 pullups) that hints at too much C. (but 1m of cable is not a lot if you have a 100kHz clock)

If you have SDA twisted with SCL, then you will have problems. If there are twisted / shielded pairs, then you should pair SDA+VCC and SCL+GND

[I2C cable crosstalk](http://www.i2cchip.com/i2c_connector.html#Crosstalk)

Make sure that your wires really are hooked up properly. Make sure you have 100nF bypass across VCC/GND at each end, so these wires are both effective gnd

Comment: On the pro micro pin out, pin 2 and 3 are SDA, SCL respectively, but the cable above is twisted but they are not shield pair, so does it means that I can't use that cable? Or are there other way around on that? Thanks

Comment: by twisted pair, I mean like UTP pairs, within the cable